# Marshalling type which references itself

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling

I have following (shortened) function definition in my c++ code:

```
EXPORT_API Table* OpenTableExport();
```

where Table is a struct of the form:

```
typedef struct Table
{
  int fCurrKey;
  int fTableNo;
  int fRecSize;
  char fCreating;
  Table* fNextTable;
  Table* fPrevTable;
  MyFileType fFile;
} Table;
```

So, to PInvoke this function from managed code I naturally tried following:

```
[DllImport("Export.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenTableExport", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,   CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Table OpenTable();
```

With following table class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public class Table
{
    public KeyDescription fCurrKey;
    public int fTableNo;
    public uint fRecSize;
    public byte fCreating;
    public Table fNextTable;
    public Table fPrevTable;
    public FileDescription fFile;

}
```

Now when using the method, I get following exception (translated from german):

> The field "fNextTable" of type "Table" can not be marshalled, no marshalling support exists for this type.

Why can't .NET marshall the fNextTable and fPrevTable members of the same type it is marshalling in any case?

I can also just replace the references in the managed class definition with IntPtr... but is this really necessary? (The marshalling then will work more or less).

Comment: You need to defined Table* fields as IntPtr.

Comment: Well, ok, I did see that possibility, I just can't see why this is necessary (the object containing these fields is marshalled correctly)

Comment: When you define the field as Table, you ask marshalling another Table structure, which creates endless recursion. IntPtr is just pointer, you get it and then pass to another API expecting Table*, or use Marshal methods to work with unmanaged memory, like PtrToStructure.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see what your getting at, makes sense in a way (although the recursion would not necessarily be endless, I guess it depends on how the marshalling is implemented). I you put that in to an answer I'll gladly accept it, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the structure by the following way:

```
public class Table
{
    public KeyDescription fCurrKey;
    public int fTableNo;
    public uint fRecSize;
    public byte fCreating;
    public IntPtr fNextTable;
    public IntPtr fPrevTable;
    public FileDescription fFile;
}
```

Test `IntPtr` members for NULL (`IntPtr.Zero`) and handle them. Probably unmanaged API contains another functions expecting `Table*`. See also `Marshal.PtrToStructure` method and another low-level `Marshal` methods for managed-unmanaged memory exchange.